# Regex string with 3 or more vowels

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that matches a String with 3 or more vowels.

I've tried this one:

[aeiou]{3,}

But it only works when the vowels are in a sequence. Any tips ?

For example:

1. Samuel -> valid
2. Joan -> invalid
3. Sol Manuel -> valid
4. Sol -> Invalid

Comment: Three or more different vowels or same ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are different or the same

Comment: @Green_Sam, post some valid and invalid examples

Comment: try like this: `(?:[aeiou][^aeiou]*){3}`

Comment: `\b\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\w*\b` Perhaps something more along the lines of this?

Comment: Just match all occurrences of `[aeiou]` and count matches.

Comment: @Green_Sam if my answer below helped, please accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it and in this case keeping it simple will probably be the most helpful to future devs maintaining that code.  That's a fun part about regexes, you can make them very efficient and clever and then very hard for somebody who doesn't do them often to update.

```
import re

regex = "[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou]"

mylist = [
"Samuel",  #yes!
"JOAN",  #no!
"Sol Manuel",  #yes!
"",  #no!
]

for text in mylist:
    if re.search(regex, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print ("Winner!")
    else:
        print ("Nein!")
```

You could also adjust each part to be [aeiouAEIOU] if you don't have an ignore case flag in your language of choice.  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

just

```
(\w*[aeuio]\w*){3,}
```

or if you want line match

```
^(.*[aeuio].*){3,}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
^.*[AEIOUaeiou].*[AEIOUaeiou].*[AEIOUaeiou].*$
```

We could also use a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*[AEIOUaeiou].*[AEIOUaeiou].*[AEIOUaeiou]).*$
```

Note that due to the possibility of backtracking I would probably prefer using the first (non lookahead) pattern because it should be more efficient.

Comment: won't that also match spaces?

Comment: @quackenator I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: a sting like `doo de` would match your first regex

Comment: Where did the OP mention anything about single words?  One of the given matching examples is `Sol Manuel`, which is two words.

Comment: The `^.*` and the `.*$` wouldn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using lookaheads like this.

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou])(?:[a-z] *)+$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou])` positive lookahead checks for presence of any character followed by vowel three times.
- `(?:[a-zA-Z] *)+` matches your one or more English words separated by spaces.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR544p/5/)**

---

**If Case insensitive Mode is OFF use following regex**

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU])(?:[a-zA-Z] *)+$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR544p/4/)**

Comment: I don't think a lookahead is the most efficient way of solving this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Agreed ! It's an alternative to direct match. Most efficient would be to match and count number of vowels as Wiktor mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using help from sniperd's answer:

```
def multi_vowel_words(text):
   pattern = r"\w+[aeiou]\w*[aeiou]\w*[aeiou]\w+"
   result = re.findall(pattern, text)
   return result
```

This works even with uppercases.

If you have numbers and underscore in your text, then instead of `\w` use `[a-zA-Z]`.